# How to create all possible binary matrices of size MxN?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have to create all possible binary matrices of size 3x5. I know there are 2^15 such matrices.
However, I dont know which function/command in Matlab can accomplish that. I have looked over the internet and couldn't find an answer.

I have tried to create all possible binary vectors of length 15. Then I converted each binary vector into a 3x5 matrix. However, this process is very time-consuming. Therefore I am looking for a Matlab command that can directly create all possible binary matrices of size 3x5.

Comment: How did you create all possible binary vectors? Please show your code.

Comment: Which process is time consuming? If you show your code, we might be able to help you speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dec2bin( ) function for this, with a little rearranging:

```
b = reshape(dec2bin(0:(2^15-1))'-'0',3,5,[])
```

The resulting 3x5 matrices will be in the first two dimensions. E.g., b(:,:,1), b(:,:,2), etc.

The above produces a double array. If you want a logical array, then

```
b = reshape(dec2bin(0:(2^15-1))'=='1',3,5,[])
```